# Monitoring Elastic Beanstalk with an ACL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

I have created a web application ElasticBeanstalk stack in AWS. My stack is in a VPC and I have applied an ACL to the VPC so that it can only be access by certain IP ranges. The monitoring aspect of Elasticbeanstalk now (rightly) shows the health of my stack as "Red". This is due (i'm guessing) to the ACL blocking cloudwatch and related AWS services from hitting my load balancer and getting the health of my stack.

How do I add AWS cloudwatch to my ACL and allow it to access my load balancer(s)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the following information on elasticbeanstalk environment health in particular when it is considered red:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.healthstatus.html

Assuming you have a non-legacy environment having the default health check on ELB is TCP:80. Have you provided a custom application healthcheck url?
ELB should be able to connect to your EC2.  That is the requirement.

What does your ACL look like?

Comment: My ACL is allowing HTTP (port 80) and HTTPS (port 443) inbound and is allowing allowing all traffic outbound. It now seems that I have trouble launching new elastic beanstalk stacks. It seems that the ACL is too strict